# Subject-verb specific case scenario

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

His potential and versatility **were** there for everyone to see

or

His potential and versatility **was** there for everyone to see?

And why?

Answer (score 1):

Of your two sentences, the first is correct:

> His potential and versatility **were** there for everyone to see.

**Were** is the simple past tense form of the of the verb **to be** which we use for plurals (as well as for 2nd person singular.) Since the subject clause in your sentence is plural, we use the plural form. If the subject clause were singular, we would use the singular form **was**:

> His potential <s>and versatility</s> **was** there for everyone to see.

Comment: Hi Dant, thank you. I have posted my response to a very similar previous answer here. Since I don't want to spam, could you please check that and tell me what you think of it?

Comment: @ALV Yes, Giambattista types faster than I do, and even more important, he didn't forget to use the right term: _compound subject_. I understand your comment above, and his answer is accurate. "Oneness of idea" refers to expressions like "Peanut butter and jelly" (as in the link) or "Hammer and sickle," in which two nouns form a single thing. We might say "The hammer and sickle **is** a symbol of international communism." But if we were looking in Bob's barn and saw that he had a hammer and a sickle there, we would say instead: "Bob's hammer and sickle **are** in the barn."

Answer (score 0):

The first example using *were* is the correct one. The reason is that it is a [compound](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/compound-subjects) [subject](https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/moduleSVAGR.htm), which makes it plural.

Because subjects and verbs must always agree in number, the plural *were* is the right choice.

Comment: The link was of massive help, thank you. Normally that settles the case, yes. Only one thing that bothers me here, though, and that is why I posted this (it is covered in the Sentencesleuth blog as well): don't they represent the "oneness of idea"? In that they form the skill set of the person in concern and hence can be interpreted as a singular subject?

Comment: You're welcome (there are actually 2 links there; the 2 words link to different sites, but the idea is the same for both). I understand where you're coming from—i.e. I believe you find the subject to be singular because the traits refer to the skill set of one particular person—but the subject of the sentence is still plural: Think of the subject more like this: ***His potential** and **his versatility** were **both** there for everyone to see* That can e elided to *His potential and versatility were there for everyone to see*, but the subject remains plural.

Comment: That makes more sense, yes. Appears to be the safest option as well. Appreciate it.